# Logical arguments are not properly constraining

Tags: python

I am having some problems with something I'm writing and cannot seem to sort out the cause.

```
dayCurrent = datetime.date.today().strftime("%j")
dayStop = (int(dayCurrent) - 14)
yearCurrent = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y")
```

The other variables are doy (Julian day of year), year, and daysVar (incrementer of days).  These three variables are inputted by the user.

```
def yearChange (doy,year,yearCurrent):
    if doy > 365:
        if calendar.isleap:
            doy = (366 - int(doy))
            year = (int(year) + 1)
        else:
            doy = (365 - int(doy))
            year = (int(year) + 1)
    return doy,year

while (yearCurrent > year) or ((int(dayStop) < int(doy)) and (yearCurrent == year)):
    doy = int(doy) + int(daysVar)
    doy,year = yearChange(doy,year,yearCurrent)
    print doy
    print year
```

When I run this, it does not stop and there's some strangeness with the subtraction.  For instance, if doy = 30, year = 2013, and daysVar = 100, I am getting this...

```
130
2013
230
2013
330
2013
2014
-64
2014
36
2014
136
2014
236
2014
```

That's where it should stop.  Instead, it keeps going on and on forever.  I am not sure where the logic breakdown is here, but I would appreciate some help, please.

Comment: You might want to use the `datetime` objects to do this kind of work. Then you can directly compare dates or use deltas (time differences).

Comment: probably you should check year **befor** 'if doy > 365:'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three problems.

The first is with how you update doy.

```
    if calendar.isleap:
        doy = (366 - int(doy))
        year = (int(year) + 1)
    else:
        doy = (365 - int(doy))
        year = (int(year) + 1)
```

should be:

```
    if calendar.isleap:
        doy = doy - 366
        year = (int(year) + 1)
    else:
        doy = doy - 365 #or with the int(doy), I don't see why it matters
        year = (int(year) + 1)
```

Let's check out the transition from 2013 to 2014. You had doy of 330, and then added a 100 - now it's 430. What you want it is to become 430 - 366 = 64, but it becomes 366-430=-64

Second - you do have a problem with your criteria. In the while loop you're not specifying a stop criteria but a "continue-criteria". So if we're at the same year, we should continue when doy is smaller than our current day, and stop when it's larger. So your while should be:

```
while (yearCurrent > year) or ((int(dayStop) > int(doy)) and (yearCurrent == year)):
```

Third - 
define your variables as integer:

```
dayCurrent = int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%j"))
yearCurrent = int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y"))
```

Otherwise `yearCurrent > year` will always be true, as python orders them alphabetically by their type name when they are not of the same type (`'str'>'int'`)

Comment: Perfect.  Your suggested changes made the difference.  I think the biggie was the integer.  I was missing that one of those was still a string and that made all the difference in the world.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try a bit differently:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.date.today()
stop = datetime.date.today - datetime.timedelta(14)
step = datetime.timedelta(100)

d = datetime.date(2013, 5, 23)

while d < stop:
    d += step
    ...
```

If you want to step from 23rd May 2013 ahead 100 days at a time until two weeks from now.

---

Another note on your code apart from the slight miscalculations is that there is an opportunity for very strange results:

```
dayCurrent = datetime.date.today().strftime("%j")
dayStop = (int(dayCurrent) - 14)
yearCurrent = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y")
```

What happens if you trigger this at 23:59:59 on the 31st of December? You may have `dayCurrent` from the previous year and `yearCurrent` from the next year. So, this should be done:

```
d = datetime.date.today()
# instead of dayCurrent, use d.timetuple().tm_yday
# instead of yearCurrent, use d.year
```

If you want to do calculations on raw dates and avoid `timedelta`, `d.toordinal()` gives you the number of the day counted from year 1. Equally, you can create a datetime object from the day nuber from year 1 by `datetime.date.fromordinal`. So, one way to count 14 days backwards is:

```
two_weeks_ago = datetime.fromordinal(d.toordinal() - 14)
```

But `timedelta` is really intended for this kind of calculations.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand the potential problems you are helping me avoid.